# Dynamically render XMLHttpRequest data to Vue element

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, vue.js, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to lazy load a list of posts from the WordPress REST API, and I want to load more news stories on click of an HTML element.

At the moment, I am having trouble accessing the original Vue instance and updating `this.data` with `response` because the async function means the instance is out of scope.

I am also duplicating code at the at the moment in `getAggregatorData` which is a standard `XMLHttpRequest` to an endpoint.

**The question: How do I access Vue instances from inside an asynchronous call (if at all possible)?**

Has anyone had any experience with lazy loading content from a REST API? This is my first refactor with Vue for this sort of technology, so happy to flesh out any questions there are.

```html
<div class="aggregator-load-more d-inline-block ta-centre my-3" v-cloak>
    <span class="bg-primary c-white px-1 py-0-5 tf-allcaps" v-on:click="lazyLoad">Load more</span>
</div>
```

```
 const news = getAggregatorData(
    'POST',
    WP_VARS.base_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/' + aggregator.endpoint, 
    aggregator,
    function(error, response){
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error: could not retrieve data');
        } else {
            aggregator.offset = response.length;
            const vueInstance = new Vue({
                el: '.aggregator',
                data: {
                    largeItems: response.slice(0, 1),
                    smallItems: response.slice(1, response.length),
                },
                methods: {
                    lazyLoad() {
                        const moreStories = getAggregatorData(
                            'POST',
                            WP_VARS.base_url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/' + aggregator.endpoint, 
                            aggregator,
                            function(error, response) {
                                if(error) {
                                    console.log('Error: failed to retrieve more news stories');
                                } else {
                                    return response;
                                }
                            });
                        this.smallItems.push(moreStories);
                    },
                },
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `lazyLoad()`, you just need to pass a reference to `this` (the Vue instance) into the callback of `getAggregatorData`. This can be simply done with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), which automatically binds `this` to the current context in the method, which is the Vue instance:

```
methods: {
    lazyLoad() {
        getAggregatorData(
            ...
          (error, response) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.log('Error: failed to retrieve more news stories');
                } else {
                    /* `this` refers to the Vue instance */
                    this.smallItems.push(response);
                }
            });
    },
},
```